# Iptables multiple port redirects based on destination address

Tags: centos, iptables

I have iptables setup for selective routing. In the current configuration it checks if the dst address is listed in a specific chain and if it is not it redirects the traffic to my proxy port which is active on port 1080.

This works fine with the following setup:

```
iptables -t nat -N PROXY
# Do not redirect
iptables -t nat -A PROXY -d external.proxy.address.1 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A PROXY -d external.proxy.address.2 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A PROXY -d 211.96.0.0/255.240.0.0 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A PROXY -d 211.128.0.0/255.128.0.0 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A PROXY -d 218.0.0.0/255.128.0.0 -j RETURN
... [and many more address] ...

# Redirect everything else to the proxy listening on port 1080
iptables -t nat -A PROXY -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1080
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -j PROXY
```

As mentioned this works fine for proxy1 but I am trying to redirect traffic in a similar way for destination 10.0.0.15 to a different proxy (proxy2) which listens on port 1088.

I've tried several ways to accomplish this without success.

Configuration I have tried :

```
iptables -t nat -A PROXY -d 10.0.0.15 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1088 # didn't do anything
```

What would be the best way to achieve this (if it's possible)

Comment: Where in the list did you put that line? If you put it after the final line in the PROXY chain it will never get hit.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is I think down to misunderstanding what `RETURN` does. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191607/iptables-and-return-target#191614 might help.

Currently, your PROXY chain works as follows:

- traffic enters the `PREROUTING` chain, where you have (as a first clause?)  `iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -j PROXY`.
- this tells iptables to evaluate your traffic against the `PROXY` chain
- the `PROXY` chain says one of two things, basically: either there is a rule with a `RETURN` action for the traffic, or there isn't, and `iptables -t nat -A PROXY -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1080` applies.
- if your traffic does match a `RETURN` entry, then iptables goes back to the `PREROUTING` chain, and evaluates the next rule. It seems there is no 'next rule' to do what you want.

The problem is this: `iptables -t nat -A PROXY -d 10.0.0.15 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1088`

You put this in the `PROXY` chain, but all the traffic to which you want this redirect to apply is actually configured to `RETURN` from (i.e. break out of) your `PROXY` chain.

What you need in place of the line above is:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.0.0.15 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1088`

The key is the *chain* in which the rule is. With this rule in PREROUTING, your `RETURN` rules will work as intended, by forcing matching traffic away from the 'default' `PROXY` rule `iptables -t nat -A PROXY -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1080`, and back into `PREROUTING`, where `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.0.0.15 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1088` can be applied.